# Problem with an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: boot, raspberrypi

I updated a raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 20.24 to ubuntu 22.04 on a 120gig ssd, but it wouldn't boot anymore.
Here are the error messages it puts on the screen (it just sits there and shows these 3 lines)

**[0.234581] Intramfs unpacking failed: Invalid magic at start of compressed archive**

**[0.44050] raspberry-clk soc: firmware: clocks: missing firware node**

**[0.862533] spi-bmc2835 fe204000.spi : could not set clk: -517**

However, I can boot the ssd  when I have a 50gig sd card with a fresh 22.04 in the pi!  I know that the updated version is running because it has a different login screen (still green whereas the fresh 22.04 has a brown login screen)

It prints this error message and proceeds to boot

**1.921226 zswap: zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud**

The error messages mean nothing to me, but maybe someone can give me a hint on how to fix this.